# How to activate and deactivate popup feature in OpenLayers2?

Tags: openlayers-2, popup, getfeatureinfo

I am a beginner in OpenLayers and I want to activate and deactivate a popup feature, which has to show lat,long of the click, which is initiating the popup [no markers].

I am currently using `OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo` and a variable to switch between getinfo and popup. But it has some issues, whenever I am clicking always it is making calls to WMS server, so I want separate controls, which I can enable and disable as I need...

Any ideas welcome...

Comment: Checked, the page with filters, I didn't get any useful example for my requirement...they are linked with markers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please look at the [OpenLayers examples](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/) to get an idea of how to do things. Search for the Custom Control example.

Now, to answer your question, I built a quick example with a control that pop an alert when you click the map. To activate or deactivate it, simply click the checkbox below the map. The example:

http://jsfiddle.net/gsgUk/